# ¿Qué parámetros debería tener el .htaccess para hacer más segura la instalación de Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Básicamente estoy configurando el .htaccess de la siguiente forma y me gustaría saber si hay algo que debo agregar para mejorar la seguridad, optimización del sitio, etc.

```
# Caché de imágenes y contenido flash un dia:

    <FilesMatch ".(flv|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=86400"
    </FilesMatch>

# Limita métodos GET y PUT de peticiones al servidor:

    Options -ExecCGI -Indexes -All
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK|OPTIONS|HEAD) RewriteRule .* - [F]

# Desactiva la navegación de directorios:

    Options All -Indexes

# Evitar el listado de carpetas:

    IndexIgnore *

# Parar el hotlinking y mostrar contenido alternativo:

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?dominio\.com/.*$ [NC]
    RewriteRule .*\.(gif|jpg)$ http://www.dominio.com/nosepermiterobar.jpg [R,NC,L]
    </ifModule>

# Requerir SSL:

    SSLOptions +StrictRequire
    SSLRequireSSL
    SSLRequire %{HTTP_HOST} eq "dominio.com"
    ErrorDocument 403 https://dominio.com

# Protección contra ataques DOS limitando el tamaño de carga de archivos:

    LimitRequestBody 10240000

# BEGIN WordPress:

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

---

Con respecto a esto, no se como aplicarlo al archivo de configuración de Wordpress donde tiene los datos de acceso a las bases de datos.

```
# Asegura el archivo htaccess:

<Files .htaccess> order allow,deny deny from all </Files>
```

Comment: Si quieres, puedes agregar [esta lista negra de User Agent](https://perishablepress.com/blacklist/ua-2013.txt), para impedir que todos esos bots piratas rastreen tu sitio. Para más detalles puedes ver este artículo: [2013 User Agent Blacklist](https://perishablepress.com/2013-user-agent-blacklist/), publicado en perishablepress. **Importante:** En el grupo `[2/3]` debes eliminar la palabra clave `via`, ya que si la dejas, te bloqueará el rastreador de Google.

Comment: Estás buscando esto: [6G Firewall 2018 | Perishable Press](https://perishablepress.com/6g/)